# Loading CRAN packages to use with emrlapply() from JD Long's 'segue' package?

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, segue, emr

I'm using JD Long's `segue` package (https://code.google.com/p/segue/) to do some parallel computing, and am running into an issue loading `CRAN` packages on the EC2 instances.

First, I created an EMR cluster like so:

```
myCluster <- createCluster(numInstances = 5, 
                           cranPackages = c("RWeka", "tm"), 
                           masterInstanceType="m1.large", 
                           slaveInstanceType="m1.large", 
                           location="us-east-1c",)
```

Per the documentation, I specified which packages I want to load (in this case, `RWeka` and `tm`).

The cluster seems to start properly, with no error messages. I am using RStudio on Linux Mint 17 with R version 3.0.2.

I wrote a function `getTerms.jobAd` which takes a character string and calls some functions from the packages above, and am using `emrlapply()` like so:

```
> jobAdTerms <- emrlapply(myCluster, X = as.list(jobAds[1:2, 3]), FUN = getTerms.jobAd)
RUNNING - 2014-06-24 17:05:19
RUNNING - 2014-06-24 17:05:50
WAITING - 2014-06-24 17:06:20
```

When I check the `jobAdTerms` list that is supposed to be returned, I get:

```
> jobAdTerms
[[1]]
[1] "error caught by Segue: Error in function (txt)  : could not find function \"Corpus\"\n"

[[2]]
[1] "error caught by Segue: Error in function (txt)  : could not find function \"Corpus\"\n"
```

Obviously, `Corpus` is one of the functions from the `tm` package.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I remedy this situation? Thanks!!

**EDIT**

Here's the function I am calling:

```
nGramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 4))

getTerms.jobAd <- function(txt) {

  tmp <- tolower(txt)
  tmp <- gsub('\\s*<.*?>|[:;,@$%^&*()?]|(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\.(?= |$)', '', tmp, perl = TRUE)

  txt.Corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(tmp))
  txt.Corpus <- tm_map(txt.Corpus, stripWhitespace)

  txt.TFV <- termFreq(txt.Corpus[[1]], control = list(dictionary = jobTags[, 1], wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))
  txt.TFV2 <- termFreq(txt.Corpus[[1]], control = list(tokenize = nGramTokenizer, dictionary = jobTags[, 1], wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))

  jobTerms <- rowSums(as.matrix(c(txt.TFV, txt.TFV2)))
  return(jobTerms)
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's how you can reproduce the error:

```
data(crude)
jobAdTerms <- emrlapply(myCluster, X = as.list(crude), FUN = getTerms.jobAd)
```

Comment: Is that parameter supposed to install the packages if they are not already present on the machine as well?

Comment: How do you suppose we are going to help when you have kept the contents of that function to yourself and you are getting error messages suggesting that the is an error in how you are calling `Corpus`?

Comment: @BondedDust I'm not really sure if you're trolling or not. To be clear, the function I am calling works perfectly find in my local environment when called with `lapply`. But since you asked, I have updated the original question with the function. Do you have any additional input?

Comment: Trolling my `<posterior>`!?! I wondered if you were dispatching `Corpus` in a weird way. The error message suggested you had called it as a string/character rather than as a real R name.